# Prompt user input when only 1 manual stored in library

Tags: java, input

I am working on a library application which allows technical manuals to be stored, borrowed, returned and deleted.

Currently I am working on the borrowing section of my application, I have enabled it to ask the user which manual they wish to borrow (from the list of manuals stored in library), by entering its designated manual index number. Shown here:

[image]

However if there is only 1 Manual stored in the library the application automatically borrows it without asking the user for an index number. Shown here:

[image]

Although it makes sense to automatically borrow the only book available, I would still prefer the user to be asked for an index number, as this would minimise confusion.

Here is the relevant code I am working with:

```
public static void borrowManual(){
    displayManualList();

    //register user's Manual choice.
    ManualChoice = (Console.readInteger(Messages.enterManualIndexMessage, Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 0, Library.ManualList.size() - 1));

    borrowLoop:
    while(Menu.menuChoice == 3){
        //Check if the Manual to be borrowed is available.
        //ManualChoice = (Console.readInteger(Messages.enterManualIndexMessage, Messages.ManualIndexNotInListMessage, 1, Library.ManualList.size()));

        if ((ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status1)) && (ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice)){
            //Print the borrowed Manual information and change the Manual status to borrowed.
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status = "Borrowed";
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrower = User.userName;
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).borrowDate = "Today.";
            ManualList.get(ManualChoice).returnDate = "In two weeks.";
            //Add the borrowed Manual to the borrowedManuals arraylist:
            borrowedManuals.add(ManualList.get(ManualChoice));

            System.out.printf("\n==========================================================================\n");
            System.out.printf("\n\nYou have chosen the following Manual:\n\n %s\n\n", ManualList.get(ManualChoice).displayManual());
            System.out.println("Please return the Manual within two weeks!\n");
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n                             Manual borrowed!\n");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            break borrowLoop;

        }else if(ManualList.get(ManualChoice).status.equalsIgnoreCase(status2) && ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice){
            System.out.println("\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("\n            "
                    + " The Manual you wish to borrow is already on loan.");
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            break borrowLoop;

        }else if(ManualChoice > ManualList.size()-1){
            System.out.println(Messages.noSuchManualMessage);
            break borrowLoop;
        }
    }
    Menu.displayMenu();
}
```

If anyone knows how I can enable my application to always ask the user for an index number input, please let me know :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your problem, if there is only 1 manual it will automatically borrow it.  I think you can just remove this && check and it should work fine.

```
(ManualList.size() >= ManualChoice)){
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried your suggestion but I am still met with the same issue :( Maybe if I could get it to only display the manual once and tell the user it has been autoselected, that would be another method, however Im not having much luck so far :(

Comment: why do you have this inside a loop?  the loop should be on the main menu, or submenu, not on the borrow or specific selection.  once a person borrows a book you should go back to the previous menu.